# Can I append apex elements to html with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a visualforce page, if I have a DOM completely created dynamically with jQuery, could I append the following code dynamically too?

```
    <div id="file">
        <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file" title="Upload Attachment" styleclass="fileType"/> 
    </div><br />
```

Can I append apex elements to html with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Visualforce](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_intro_what_is_it.htm) actually renders into HTML on the server and gets returned to the client as just HTML (with some other stuff like the view state, etc). So, adding an `<apex:inputFile>` dynamically straight to the DOM via javascript simply isn't going to work. I would suggest if you need to use Visualforce specifically, use an [`<apex:actionSupport>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm) to dynamically refresh a specific section based on an event. However, you won't be able to rerender an `<apex:inputFile>` or you will get an error like:

> apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action
>   component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a
>   rerender or oncomplete attribute

Your best bet may be to render the `<apex:inputFile>` somewhere in a hidden `<div>` on the page, and then grab the HTML generated ([using `html()` function in jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/html/)) and put it where you need it to be. I'm not 100% sure that would work, but it would be the path I would go down to start. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, the page is made up of one big block of jQuery which repeats a number of times depending on how many entries there are in a DB. And I need to add my code once in each block when it renders... Tricky.